# properties of the resolvent

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory

Let $A$ be an operator with compact resolvent in a Hilbert space. I want to ask if the resolvent set of this operator is a dence subset in $\mathbb{C}$?

Comment: Compact subsets are never dense in $\mathbb C$!

Comment: @s.harp: But the resolvent set is almost never compact. Notice that "compact resolvent" means that the operator $(A-z)^{-1}$ is compact and not that the resolvent set $\rho(A)$ is compact.

Comment: @MaoWao, thanks, that makes sense to me

Answer (score 2):

Let $A$ be a *closed* linear operator (otherwise the question makes little sense) and $z_0\in \rho(A)$. From the identity
$$
A-z=((A-z_0)^{-1}-(z-z_0)^{-1})(A-z_0)(z_0-z)
$$
one can easily see that $z\in \sigma(A)$ if and only if $(z-z_0)^{-1}\in \sigma((A-z_0)^{-1})$.

If $(A-z)^{-1}$ is compact, then $\sigma((A-z)^{-1})$ has no accumulation point except $0$. Thus, $\sigma(A)$ has no accumulation point, so it certainly does not contain an open disk. It follows that $\rho(A)=\mathbb{C}\setminus\sigma(A)$ is dense in $\mathbb{C}$.

Comment: Thanks, but I haven't understand how if $\sigma(A)$ does not contain an open disk then the resolvent set is dense in $\mathbb{C}$.

Comment: This is more or less the definition of being a dense subset: $\overline{\rho(A)}$ is the smallest closed subset containing $\rho(A)$, hence $\mathbb C\setminus\overline{\rho(A)}$ is the biggest open subset contained in $\mathbb C\setminus\rho(A)=\sigma(A)$. If $\sigma(A)$ does not contain an open disk, then $\mathbb C\setminus\overline{\rho(A)}$ is empty.

Comment: Can you explain to me how if $\sigma((A-z)^{-1})$ has no accumulation point except 0, thus, $\sigma(A)$ has no accumulation point?

Comment: The line above shows that $\sigma((A-z)^{-1})=(\sigma(A)-z)^{-1}$. If $(z_n)$ is a sequence in $\sigma(A)$ converging to $a\in\mathbb{C}$, then $(z_n-z)^{-1}$ converges to $(z_n-a)^{-1}$. But since $\sigma((A-z)^{-1})$ has no accumulation point besides $0$, this is impossible.